# Regular languages for which star height is not increased by complementation

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, kleene-star

The set of (non-generalized) regular expressions over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is the set of expressions generated by the following grammar, where $a\in \Sigma$ ranges over symbols in the alphabet:
$$
\pi ::= \epsilon \mid \emptyset \mid a \mid \pi_1\cdot\pi_2 \mid \pi_1\cup\pi_2 \mid \pi^*.
$$
Here, $\epsilon$ stands for the language containing only the empty word and $\emptyset$ stands for the empty language. The *star height $h(\pi)$ of a regular expression $\pi$* is defined as the maximum nesting depth of Kleene stars in $\pi$, i.e., we have:

- $h(\epsilon) := 0$, $h(\emptyset) := 0$ and $h(a):= 0$ for all $a\in \Sigma$,
- $h(\pi_1\cdot\pi_2) := \max\{h(\pi_1), h(\pi_2)\}$ and $h(\pi_1\cup\pi_2) := \max\{ h(\pi_1), h(\pi_2)\}$,
- $h(\pi^*) := h(\pi) +1$.

Finally, the *star height $H(L)$ of a regular language $L$* is the minimum star height among all regular expressions describing $L$, so we have:
$$
H(L) := \min \{ h(\pi)\mid \text{$\pi$ is a regular expression and $L=L(\pi)$}\}.
$$
It was shown by [Eggan (1963)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-10/issue-4/Transition-graphs-and-the-star-height-of-regular-events/10.1307/mmj/1028998975.full) and [Dejean & Schützenberger (1966)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995866900830?via%3Dihub) that there exist regular languages of arbitrary star height, even over a two-element alphabet. In particular, it is possible to prove that, for any $n\geq 0$, the regular expression $\pi_n$ inductively defined below describes a language of star height $n$ (that is, it holds $H(L(\pi_n)) = n$).

- $\pi_1 := (ab)^*$,
- $\pi_{n+1} := (\underbrace{a\cdots a}_{2^n} \cdot e_n \cdot \underbrace{b\cdots b}_{2^n} \cdot e_n)^*$.

However, as shown by [Cohen & Brzozowski (1970, Proposition 5.4)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.8917&rep=rep1&type=pdf), taking the complement of a regular language may **increase** the star height of the language. More specifically, for every integer $m\geq 0$, there exists a regular language $L$ such that $H(\overline{L}) \geq H(L) + m$.

My question is now whether we can also find, for every $n\geq 1$, a regular language $L$ of star height $n$ such that the star height is **not** increased by taking the complement. More precisely: is it true that, for every $n\geq 1$, there exists a regular language $L$ such that $H(L) = n$ and $H(\overline{L}) \leq n$?

Comment: I don't think this is true for $n=0$, since $L$ is finite $\iff$ $H(L)=0$, and if $L$ is finite, then $\overline L$ isn't finite.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! I've now edited the question in order to exclude the case $n=0$.

Comment: See the remark after Proposition 5.2 in Cohen & Brzozowski.